# How can I maintain the curl handle for (async) queued jobs?

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I am letting do some curl connection work to workers. Each job inits a new curl handle. Sometimes more than 100 jobs. I was wondering if there is a way to somehow store the curl handle and then use it in the jobs. Because there are many jobs (connections) I am hoping to gain more speed by not auth and connecting each time from the beginning.

Actually I searched a lot but could not find any helping information. Any info would be great. Even knowing that there isn't a solution for this would come handy. I can't stop looking into this because there is no precise info out there.

ps: In a strange way I can't use guzzle for the connections because I get errors on the api (when I use guzzle) I am connecting to.

Comment: You can save cookies to a jar https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html you use it in php along the lines of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__.'/cookie.txt');`

Comment: @Dhiraj what speed advantage would that give to me. Would it pass the authentication process or would it affect the connection speed as well?

Comment: It will give you a major speed advantage, it works same way authentication works in a browser since curl is pretty much a separate browser

Comment: @Dhiraj Then I will try it. Last question Is it possible to store that into cache or must it be a file?

Comment: As far as I know, it only supports a file with proper permissions (read and write)

Comment: @Dhiraj Thank you I am going to try it.

Comment: But are you actually having performance issues? i worked on queue setups that could process 100k jobs pretty fast and no problems there (thou we used guzzle but i guess curl should be just as fast)

Comment: @mrhn Actually I tried to make the connection part without workers. When I test them whithout curl_init() for each process then It is slightly faster. But when I curl_init for each execution then it is slower. Sadly in queued jobs I have no chance to store (keep alive the previously initialized curl handle) and use it on every job asynchronously. Instead I must init a new one for each job. So it can't be said directly that there are performance issues, but an obligation.

Comment: why was it guzzle then was not working?

Comment: @mrhn no idea actually may be because it was soap api. after I changed to curl it worked. I have no clear support from the api side so I didn't try more and continued with curl.